# Lost access to my account email

Tags: support, login

I have lost access to the email address for my Stack Overflow account.  I can still login... but it would be really good to fix this, so that any emails from Stack Overflow actually reach me.  Is there a place where I can go to change this? I don't want to just start a new account, because I have far too much reputation and question history on this one. In related questions I see references to OpenID, but I don't know what that is and I don't know if I have one. Please help.

Comment: How about this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327313/how-do-i-change-my-email-address-for-my-stack-exchange-login